# What does the ? mean in this equation? (x ? y) % 255

Tags: math

does anyone with a maths background know what is meant by the question mark in the following equation, as found in the PDF here: http://ivizlab.sfu.ca/media/GenProg2009.pdf ?

```
(x ? y) % 255
```

Obviously `% 255` is the modulus function but I can't think what they mean by the question mark. All my experience of programming tells me that `?` is conditional such as `x > y ? 1 : 2` but I don't think that is the case here.

I am implementing a set of graphical functions that generate random images and the functions are called for each x and y coord in the image.

Other functions listed in the source document use the same notation such as:

```
(x ? y) / 2
```

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: by the way, I'm porting the function set into c# FYI

Comment: source document can be found here: http://ivizlab.sfu.ca/media/GenProg2009.pdf

Comment: No it doesn't explain it as far as I can understand, it just lists the functions as the functions used in the calculations. I'm trying to replicate the same sort of function set but am having problems with the functions using the ? notation

Comment: Where does the notation come from? What does the `?` mean? It is not C#, so you need to explain the notation before anyone can help.

Comment: Why not e-mail: liane.gabora@ubc.ca or sdipaola@sfu.ca and ask them to clarify? Could just be an error.

Comment: I removed the C# tag as it is quite misleading. The original code from the paper is some sort of pseudo-code.

Comment: When trying this it won't work. The compiler expects a ":". So the compiler obviously tries to parse this as a ternary operator.

Comment: Well if it is pseudo code and we don't have the definition, it could mean anything...

Comment: it doesn't compile, it is totally wrong, are you sure you are talking C#?

Comment: @CuongLe: it is not C#, it is some kind of pseudo code. So how should he try or compile?

Comment: There appears to be an issue with the PDF; judging by their source (http://www.emoware.org/evolutionary_art.asp), it's not supposed to look like that. (There's another place where they appear to use `[` as an operator, which is even more wrong). My guess is that it's *supposed* to read `(x + y) % 255`, since that is the only character not represented in that list, but represented in the source functions.

Comment: I second @MichaelMadsen, check the referenced paper at http://www.emoware.org/work/ashmore-miller-evomusart2004.zip

Comment: This is still a too localized question, since it's only going to help people looking at this specific paper for this specific purpose.

Answer (score 10):

Executive summary: [The paper you link to](http://ivizlab.sfu.ca/media/GenProg2009.pdf) ("DiPaola & Gabora") has has some formatting problems, which prevent comprehension. You should search for actual code associated with the paper, or contact the authors.

---

Note that on page 4, they say

> Our work is based on Ashmore and Miller’s [2] CGP application

Chasing reference 2 leads eventually to this paper: http://www.emoware.org/work/ashmore-miller-evomusart2004.zip (zip containing PDF) ("Ashmore & Miller"), in which a similar set of functions are defined, however in this second paper, it can be seen that the PDF of DiPaola & Gabora has lost superscript formatting: where it has

> 13: abs (sqrt (x - param2 ? y - param2) % 255);

it should actually have

> 13: abs (sqrt (x - param<sup>2</sup> ? y - param<sup>2</sup>) % 255);

(note, `param` *squared* rather than `param2`)

Simlarly, where Ashmore & Miller has

> 3: (input1 * input2) % 255;
>
> 4: (input1 + input2) % 255;
>
> 5: if(input1>input2) input1 - input2; else input2 - input1;

DiPaola & Gabora ends up with

> 3: (x ? y) % 255;
>
> 4: if (x[y) x - y; else y - x;

It seems clear to me that **some non-ASCII symbol was intended where the `?` appears**. This may have been a unicode PLUS or TIMES, but I can't be sure. Also note that the `>` from the original has become a `[`, which is nonsense.

In the face of these formatting errors, the thing to do is either try a few things and see what works; search for reference **source code** by the authors; or (as a last resort) contact DiPaola & Gabora and ask them what was intended.